# Add extra upload field in dokan payment form

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, dokan

Hi i want to upload **cancel cheque** image in payment setting. 
Already find the code to add seller url

https://gist.github.com/nayemDevs/b629d4b1c27c794bdfb729ce6927069e

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately this is not a coding service. You will find help if you provide some code (in your question) and a unstandable concrete problem. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example") of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: i provided a link and if  i change the input type text to file its not working

Comment: Now Solved used the old banner function :)